# React Native: 'top' property behaving as expected, but 'bottom' isn't

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, css-position

I have the following code in my React Native app:

```
<View
  style={{
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
  }}
>
  <View style={{
    width: 5,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    top: 10,
    left: 10
  }}></View>
</View>
```

As expected, this results in:

[image]

However, if I swap `top` for `bottom`, I get this:

[image]

If I change the child element to `position: absolute`, it works as expected:

[image]

**What I Want To Know:**

1) Why does the red dot go above the black square in the second image?

2) Since the red dot is the only child of the black square, why does adding `position: absolute` change anything?

3) Why does `top` behave as expected in all three images, but `bottom` behaves as expected only in the third?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React-Native, every layout element is relatively positioned by default, so 10px relatively from the bottom of initial position lays out of the container, it is proper behavior.

Set the child's position to absolute, if You want to position the dot against the bounds of the container.

```
    <View
      style={{
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        borderWidth: 1,
        position: 'relative' // by default anyway
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          width: 5,
          height: 5,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          bottom: 10,
          left: 10,
          position: 'absolute'
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Hi Mateusz, Re "from the bottom of initial position": do you mean that React Native looks at the initial position of the red dot, and shifts it upward by 10, whereas if I set its position to absolute, it calculates the final position relative to the parent container rather than the initial position of the child element itself?

Comment: Exactly :) @gkeenley

Comment: Ok thanks, and even though its the default as you pointed out, what difference does it make to this scenario to have position: relative on the parent element?

Comment: It does not have matter, I have marked that it's relative by default anyway, so you can erase this "position:relative" and it will be working the same way.

Answer (score 2):

1) Because without specifying `position: absolute` all position commands are relative to where the element is initially.

2)  It changes how the positions commands (top, left, right, bottom ) are interpreted relative to the parent element

3) Because `top` refers to the same place regardless of what `position` is set to, but `buttom` could refer to a different place depending on if you have `position` set to relative or absolute

Comment: Hi Travis, this makes sense, thanks! The other guy had a good answer too and got it in first, so I have to approve his answer, but still gave you the thumbs up.

Comment: No worries!  Glad I was able to help!  To answer the question you asked in the comments of the other answer, adding position: 'relative' to the parent won't make any difference at all because that is what all elements default to.

Comment: Ok cool. In general though, does setting position to absolute or relative on a parent have any direct effect on the child?

Comment: No,  if you set position: 'absolute' on a parent element and then change the positioning of that element it will move the element and everything inside it, but it doesn't change the layout of the child elements within the parent.